# Android Location based application

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android application where I need to calculate the total distance travelled by the vehicle, the time taken so far and the waiting time, similar to ola app. How should I proceed

Answer (score 0):

Navigation Services in maps is provided under the class maps.google.com and the response you get is in the KML format.

To get kml file we need to form url with start and destination locations:

```
public static String getUrl(double fromLat, double fromLon,
double toLat, double toLon) {// connect to map web service
StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");
urlString.append("&saddr=");// from
urlString.append(Double.toString(fromLat));
urlString.append(",");
urlString.append(Double.toString(fromLon));
urlString.append("&daddr=");// to
urlString.append(Double.toString(toLat));
urlString.append(",");
urlString.append(Double.toString(toLon));
urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
return urlString.toString();
}
```

Next you need to create a Object class which will parse xml (implemented with SAXParser) and fill data structures:

```
public class Point {
String mName;
String mDescription;
String mIconUrl;
double mLatitude;
double mLongitude;
}

public class Road {
public String mName;
public String mDescription;
public int mColor;
public int mWidth;
public double[][] mRoute = new double[][] {};
public Point[] mPoints = new Point[] {};
}
```

The full source code for this particular example cam be found out in this [link](https://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/source/browse/trunk/J2MEMapRouteBlackBerryEx/src/org/ci/geo/route/RoadProvider.java).

The main line in that class is when it makes a call to getURL and getRoute method.

```
public static String getUrl(double fromLat, double fromLon,
double toLat, double toLon)
```

And to get the route of the source and drestination you need to make a call to this method.

```
public static Road getRoute(InputStream is)
```

To implement this piece of code in the Adroid app please take a look at the following code:

```
public class MapRouteActivity extends MapActivity {    
LinearLayout linearLayout;
MapView mapView;
private Road mRoad;    
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);    
new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
double fromLat = 49.85, fromLon = 24.016667; 
double toLat = 50.45, toLon = 30.523333;
String url = RoadProvider
  .getUrl(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon);
InputStream is = getConnection(url);
mRoad = RoadProvider.getRoute(is);
mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
}.start();
}

Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
textView.setText(mRoad.mName + " " + mRoad.mDescription);
MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(mRoad, mapView);
List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
listOfOverlays.clear();
listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
mapView.invalidate();
};
};

private InputStream getConnection(String url) {
InputStream is = null;
try {
URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
is = conn.getInputStream();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return is;
}    
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
return false;
}
}
```

Hope that would help!!!

Comment: I would get the route of starting point and end point, but I will not get the distance travelled so far